# Calculate total resistance. (Circuit analysis)

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, resistance, series, ohms-law

How do I solve this circuit and determine the total resistance between A and B if all the resistors are 120 Ω?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is appears to be homework with no effort to solve it.

Comment: If you are going to be doing electrical engineering thingys, you should familiarize your self with circuit emulators. Two birds one stone IMHO.

Comment: And for homework problem like this (drawn in an unconventional way) try redrawing it. It's more like a puzzle then then problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can the middle three resistors be simplified somehow if they were in parallel or series? The net resistance that you obtain with them can be added with the other two.
You should be able to solve this now.